# Why does my php not follow the standard sequence

Tags: php, laravel

I made the following function in a laravel project:

```
  public function index()
  {
    $start = microtime(true);

    foreach (User::where('email', 'admin@admin.nl')->get() as $flight) {
        echo 'you';
    }

    echo "<br>";
    echo 'time ';
    echo microtime(true) - $start;
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

To my surprise the result was the following:

```
time 0.023716926574707
you
```

For some reason the order has changed. Does anyone know why the script behaves in this strange way?

Comment: Sounds very unlikely, are you sure you are not echoing out `you` somewhere else and there are no rows found?

Comment: Nope the script you see is all there is in an empty project, this is what I found so strange. I made the projects minutes before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your config, output is cached until completion.
You can force a flush with either ob_flush() or flush(). Sadly many modern browser also dont update until page load is complete, no matter how often you flush.

flush http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

ob_flush http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php